# How to change column value, when user change page

Tags: oracle-apex

I trying to update the column value when the user clicks on page from menu.
for example, when the user is on page 1, I have to update the column to 1, and when the user clicks on any other page from the menu, I have to update column to 0.

I tried with DA, but I can't update column to 0 when user click on page from menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to update a column in a table whenever a page is accessed.

You can do this by defining an application process which runs "On Load - Before Header". This process can have the PL/SQL logic to update your table.
In PL?SQL, you can get the current page that was accessed using `v('APP_PAGE_ID')`.